# Emacs subshell: how to select options by moving up and down arrow keys?

Tags: key-bindings, shell

I open a subshell session using <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> `shell` and I create a [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/) application using: `yarn create nuxt-app myproject`.

During the installation process, I am suggested which packages/frameworks/libraries/tools to use for my development process as shown on this screenshot:

[image]

On Ubuntu's Terminal I just press the arrows down or up to select what I want. But with the subshell session these arrows do not work. How to achieve my goal?

Comment: What exactly is this "subshell session" you're talking about? `M-x` on its own doesn't tell what command you've invoked. Have you executed `M-x shell` or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake, I meant as you said `M-x shell` @wasamasa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-x shell` starts a shell inside a so-called dumb terminal. It can send and display text, but that's it. Anything fancy includes extra leg work.

What you'll want to use for the full interactive experience is `M-x term`. It supports all the bells and whistles of a terminal emulator, at the expense of being far slower than `M-x shell`.